# Cannot send/receive MMS on Project Fi with unlocked Blu Advance A6

Tags: mms, apn, project-fi

I have been trying to get my [unlocked Blu Advance A6](https://smile.amazon.com/BLU-Advance-Unlocked-Dual-Smartphone/dp/B071KGHXWY) on Android 7.0 working with Project Fi and I can't seem to get MMS messages working in the default app or Signal.

Regular text messages can be sent and received OK, but when an MMS comes in it just says "Tap to download" and when I try to send one it says "Not sent. Tap to try again."

I thought that maybe it was due to the APN settings being incorrect but the **Access point names** menu that is supposed to be located in **Settings -> Wireless & Networks -> More -> Cellular networks** is missing. There is only a toggle for **Data roaming** and no other items.

[image: Cellular networks menu]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it appears that installing [Google Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk) makes messaging work. Although the app is pretty slow.

For the APN settings, the Project Fi app disables that menu when it's installed according to this: 
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/nexus/F9TYPTE11to

According to that post, you can run this from an adb shell to re-enable it:

```
settings put global hide_carrier_network_settings 0
```